# Problem on map name on arrow

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-cd

I have an issue with double map: I can't put the maps names on the right place, one on the top of the arrow, the other on the bottom.

[image]

```
\begin{tikzcd}
    X'' \arrow[r, shift right, "", "h"]
        \arrow[r, shift left, "g", ""']
    & X' \arrow[r, "f"]
    & X
\end{tikzcd}
```

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to swap the position of `h`:

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,tikz-cd}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzcd}
    X'' \arrow[r, shift right, swap, "h"]
        \arrow[r, shift left, "g"]
    & X' \arrow[r, "f"]
    & X
\end{tikzcd}

\end{document}
```

Also `\arrow[r, shift right,"h"']` would do.

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much for your help!